# Warnings compiling SCSS regarding the use of '/' for division

Tags: css, dart, math, sass

I've opened up an old project which was previously 'valid' (years ago), however now I'm getting a lot of errors around depreciated methods in Dart SASS. Mainly to do with math / division.

The majority of these look like they're to do with using declarations like `margin-top: $gutter / 2;` and the suggestion is to use `margin-top: math.div($gutter, 2);` and I'd need to include `@use "sass:math";`?

My question being, it it work including this and working this way or is it a lot of fuss when you could just use CSS `calc` to achieve the same thing maybe?

Aside from these 'regular' declarations the only other place I can think of where I use math is in a Mixin for font sizes (px + rem), which might be so out of date now anyways...

```
@mixin font-size($font-size: 16){
font-size : #{$font-size}px;
font-size : #{$font-size / 10}rem;}
```

I'd appreciate some recommendations - thanks in advance!

Comment: CSS's `calc` is not as powerful as SASS's expression support, fwiw.

Comment: "or is it a lot of fuss when you could just use CSS calc to achieve the same thing maybe?" - if you can do it with `calc` _without_ using SASS then I recommend doing that.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to specify `font-size` in `px` units. You can stick to using _only_ `rem` for `font-size` (though I personally use percentages, but I'm weird).

Comment: @Dai yeah I was thinking the px/rem is outdated now. Would've just been from an old 'theme' I used years ago. I'll still with SASS then at least to get experience from it. So I literally just need to include `@use "sass:math"` then I can use `math.div` and that's it?

Comment: "So I literally just need to include @use "sass:math" then I can use math.div and that's it?" - Correct.

Comment: @Dai if I have multiple SCSS files, do I need to include `@use "sass:math";` in all of them? I updated on file and it worked great. Then in another I got an error saying it was an undefined function? Maybe I should include whatever `@use "sass:math";` is in a file as well?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `@use "sass:math"` to every SCSS file where you want to use `math.div`.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! I actually added it to the top of my `_theme.scss` which pulls in all the `.scss` files before compiling and that seems to work (at the minute) so that might be the way to go - thanks again for all this advice, amazing! :)

Comment: Look [here](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div) for info about the breaking change. There is an official migration tool, you don't need to do it all by hand.